# Validation issue in select2 multiple select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validated select2 and other input fields they are validating as shown in code snippet, but i do not want to show text on validation error instead i want to show red border around select2 and textbox, i have used that too in error placement and highlight section but it is not showing any red border around fields.

```js
$("#singleselect").select2({ placeholder: "Please select",width: '100%'});
    $.validator.messages.required = '';
        $("form#msform").validate({
            ignore:'input[type=hidden]',
            rules:
            {
                "singleselect[]": { required: true },
        name: { required: true }

        },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                var elem = $(element);
                if (elem.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
                    element = $("#select2-" + elem.attr("id") + "-container").parent(); 
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                } 
                else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                
                var elem = $(element);
                if (elem.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
                    $("#select2-" + elem.attr("id") + "-container").parent().addClass(errorClass); 
                } 
                else if(elem.is(':checkbox'))
                {
                    elem.addClass("parent-error"); 
                    
                }
                else {
                    elem.addClass(errorClass);
                }
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                var elem = $(element);
                if (elem.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
                     $("#select2-" + elem.attr("id") + "-container").parent().removeClass(errorClass);
                }
                else if(elem.is(':checkbox'))
                {
                    elem.removeClass("parent-error"); 
                    
                }
                else {
                    elem.removeClass(errorClass);
                }
            }, 
            success: function (label, element) {
                //jQuery(element).parent().removeClass('has-error');
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
```

```css
span.error{
    outline: 1px solid red;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.parent-error {
    outline:1px solid red;
    background:red;
}

#msform label.error {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="msform" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" novalidate="novalidate">
<select class="sl" id="singleselect" name="singleselect[]" multiple>
            <option value="val1">Val-1</option>
            <option value="val2">Val-2</option>
        </select>
 <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" maxlength="80" size="30" class="form-control error" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Name" aria-invalid="true">       
        
 <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">       
</form>
```

Comment: Where is select2?

Comment: Why do you have an `errorPlacement` function when you don't want to show any error `label` elements?  Just put a `return false` inside of it.   You're telling it to insert `label` elements that you have hidden with CSS.   This makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has to do with your targeting logic.

```
if (elem.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible"))
```

You do not have anything in the DOM with that class.  The hidden `select` element only has a class of `sl`.

Then you are trying to target an element with an ID of `select2-" + elem.attr("id") + "-container"`, however, no such thing exists.  I set up a jsFiddle, inspected the DOM, and the ID of the container is `s2id_singleselect`.

https://jsfiddle.net/8ganq0mt/1/

I also removed a lot of unnecessary code.  There is no need to blank out the actual message or hide with CSS.  If you don't want error messages, then don't use the `errorPlacement` callback to place the messages; just `return false` and messages are gone.

```
errorPlacement: function() {
    return false;
},
```